# Crear base datos en Symfony4

Tags: symfony4

Estoy tratando de crear una base de datos en Symfony 4 con `php bin/console doc:data:create` pero me da este error:

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:

  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using pa
  ssword: YES)


In PDOConnection.php line 31:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


In PDOConnection.php line 27:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


doctrine:database:create [--shard SHARD] [--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-
|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <com
and>
```

¿qué puedo hacer para que me permita crear dicha base de datos?

Comment: pues ahi el error indica que te estas tratando de conectar usando para ello una contraseña o que no es necesaria o que esta mal escrita, ya verificaste eso?

Comment: Tienes razón, no habia modificado el archivo .env en la linea: DATABASE_URL=mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name
Gracias!

Comment: te lo colocaré como respuesta entonces @RicardoKra

Answer (score 1):

Te adelanto que tienes que configurar bien el .env

Pon esto: Si el root tiene contraseña

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:contraseña@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony
```

Sin contraseña

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony
```

Y esto debería funcionar.

Comment: Te comento que responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad, dale editar y agrega todo aquí